# How to remove number from string after a specific character C#

Tags: c#

I have a string that i need to remove the last number from the string.
For example
abc/wed/ash/123 or
abc/tues/1 or
abc/thurs/clou/nice/12

The string does not have a set amount of / in it, however I would like to separate the number after the last / from the string.

Therefore I would like to get 
abc/wed/ash and 123

Everything I found needed a set amount of / in it for it to work.

Comment: Use `LastIndexOf` to find the last slash and `Substring` to remove it.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Why is this tagged as SQL?

Comment: Would like to know how to do it using a SQL query. For the future if I need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the last index of "/" on your input string, then use that result in Substring:

```
var input = "abc/wed/ash/123";
var lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf("/");
var part1 = input.Substring(0, lastIndex); // "abc/wed/ash"
var part2 = input.Substring(lastIndex + 1); // "123"
```

Comment: @user3590040 just an FYI there is an answer with 4 upvotes, that was actually answered earlier than the one you marked.  Plus it actually gives you an int number instead of a string

Answer (score 5):

If you need both halves you could try this:

```
var s = "abc/thurs/clou/nice/12";
var index = s.LastIndexOf('/');

var number = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(index + 1)); //12

var leftHalf = s.Substring(0, index); //abc/thurs/clou/nice
```

Comment: Simplest and most efficient answer.  +1

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a variety of approaches, the cleanest approach is the answer by Francies.  Which would be:

```
// Performant:
var input = "/Product/Electrical/Wire/4421";
var index = input.LastIndexOf('/');

var id = int.Parse(input.Substring(index + 1));
var url = input.Substring(0, index);
```

You could also do the following, which is a nice alternative syntax wise:

```
// Easy to read syntax.
var input = "/Product/Electrical/Wire/4421";
var id = input.Skip(input.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var url = input.Take(input.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

If you only need the number, you could do:

```
var input = "/Product/Electrical/Wire/4421";
var id = input.Split('/').Last();
```

Comment: Some critiques on your first code example. The iterator on the `Where` is a STRING, representing the group of characters between each slash.

Comment: @maccettura I fixed my answer, should be a solid one.  Another nice approach in the middle I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
const string Input = "abc/def/123";
var regex = new Regex(@"(.+)/(\d+)$");
foreach (var group in regex.Match(Input).Groups)
    Console.WriteLine(group.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

**UPDATE**

OK, maybe I should do some explaining. By specifying a pattern, you can express quite cleanly what are the parts of your input that are of interest to you. In this case, for example, the pattern `@(.+)/(\d+)` tells the engine that you expect the input to contain any number of any characters, then a dash, then a number of digits. $ means that should be the end of the input.

When processing text input, consider regular expressions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*?)(\d+)$");
        Match match = regex.Match("abc/tues/1");
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); -->abc/tues/
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value); -->1
```

Comment: Regex is overkill for this, I would avoid Rgex for this entirely

Comment: @maccettura I don't see how it is overkill. In number of lines of code, there is basically no difference, compared to the `LastIndexOf()` method. I understand why someone would not put effort into it when it's just finding the last dash, but why should you avoid it?

Comment: @tgz number of lines of code is not how you determine efficiency.

Comment: This only gives me the last number so if I had 12 instead of 1, I only get the 2 and not 12

Comment: @tgz The quantity and lines are a factor, the more often you execute an expression will perform significantly slower, because they're designed for flexibility.